# How can this table possibly be converted to a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I got a TABLE in Excel format like:

[image]

[SEE LARGE IMAGE HERE](http://ctrlv.in/459785)

This is a **STEN TABLE** containing `FACTORS (A,B,C,D,E....etc)`

Each **Factor** is like a separate test.

Each **Factor** *i.e. Factor A* has a `[Raw Score]` and a `[Sten]`

Supposing **Factor A**, had a question like:

```
-----------------------------------
```

**Why do humans have Eyes?**

*The answer options could be like:*

> **a)** To Watch movies =  *[Raw Score] -> 10,*
>
> **b)** To Read Novels  =  *[Raw Score] -> 5,*
>
> **c)** To close them while sleeping = *[Raw Score] ->0*

So if they Chose **a)** then, the system will go to the `STEN TABLE` to get the `STEN` Equivalent under `Factor A`, in this case, the **sten** equivalent will be `4`. `(See Factor A->Row score 10-> Sten column)`

What could be the most practical way to have this STEN TABLE with Factors and their Raw Scores and Stens created?

Something like:

```
              **STEN TABLE**
                         |
                         |
                **FACTORS (A,B,C,D...)**
                      /     \
                     /       \
                    /         \
                   /           \
                  /             \
            **[Raw Score]      [Sten]**
                    


-----------------------
```

**EDIT 1:**

**To a larger image, please click here:** http://ctrlv.in/459785

Please note that, the `sten`s are not equal for all **Factors**, though the `Raw Scores` are the same. *i.e.* in **Factor A**, `[Raw Score]->3 = [sten]->2` but in **Factor C**  `[Raw Score]->3  = [sten]->1` and in **Factor F**  `[Raw Score]->1 [sten]->2` whereas in **Factor E**  `[Raw Score]->1 = [sten]->1`.

Any Suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: To a larger image, please click here: http://ctrlv.in/459785

Answer (score 0):

The table structure should be:

```
Questions
fields: id, factor, text

Answers
fields: id, question_id, text, raw_score

Sten-table(s)
fields: id; factor, raw_score, sten
```

The id is a unique primary auto-incrment field identifying the line. When you get the answer to a question, you take the factor from the question and the raw_score from the answer and do a simple select on the Sten-table like

```
SELECT sten FROM sten_table WHERE factor = 'A' AND raw_score = 10
```

**EDIT**
The Sten-table would have all lines from your Excel-sheet below eachother:
id, factor, raw_score, sten
1, A, 1, 1
2, A, 2, 1
3, A, .....
...
22, B, 1, 1
23, B, 2, 1
...

Comment: Thanks for the Idea, but please not that the `sten` are not equal for all **Factors**. Please see **EDIT 1**... Thank you

Comment: Could you not keep the above table structure, but have 22 x 5 entries in the sten-table - i.e. 1, A, 0, 1 .... 108, F, 22, 0 with everything in between. You then could retrieve the factor (to link with the sten-table) from the answer 'text' and the raw score from the answer itself to return the sten?

Comment: @Simeon Sounds Great, please can you post this as an *Answer* rather than a *Comment* and explain clearer... thank you

Comment: sorry if this was not clear, the sten-table was meant like Simeon explained. I have added the table content above in my answer